# Transaction table stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a transaction table (Id,UserId,FirstName,LastName,Products,Amount,CreatedDate)

I want to write a procedure say 'summarizeAmountByLastName' that accepts parameters @LastName,@Startdate,@EndDate,@MinimumSummedAmount and returns appropriate data from transaction table.

I'm new to writing stored proc like this. Things I tried is

```
SELECT UserId,FirstName,LastName,Products,SUM(Amount) as SummedAmount,
CreatedDate
from TestTable 
where CreatedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate 
group by UserId,FirstName,LastName,Products,Amount,CreatedDate
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What you write is likely to parameterized query. To write stored procedure refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx#TsqlProcedure) documentation.

Comment: Your procedure objective is not clear can you explain a bit more. Like what is the use `@MinimumSummedAmount` input parameter

Answer (score 0):

you might need to play with it a bit, but likely you are looking for something like this for the query for your stored proc. refer to link posted by @Hamlet for syntax for creating stored proc.

```
SELECT UserId,FirstName,LastName,Products,SUM(Amount) as SummedAmount,
CreatedDate
from TestTable 
where 
    CreatedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate 
    and LastName = @LastName
group by UserId,FirstName,LastName,Products,Amount,CreatedDate
having  SUM(Amount) > @MinTotal
```